# How do I use an Xpages onchange event to activate a button

Tags: javascript, xpages

I am trying to find how to make an onChange event for a check box initiate a button press for a button on the same page.  I have had a search on google but can't find how this is done.  Is such a thing possible in xpages?

EDIT: More information and code

My problem is the users run a search and want the option to omit cancelled records or include them.  I tried for days to get the view to update just by clicking on a checkbox but it would only refresh after the user changed the check box value and clicked somewhere on the page.  I tried partial refresh and complete refresh etc on the check box to refresh the dynamicviewpanel etc.  I tried using viewScope variables to determine the check box value but nothing worked.  I found it worked if I included a button to do a complete refresh and I thought I could hide the button and have the check box click the button.  I have tried adding Knut's suggestion below but it still only works when I click also the button or somewhere else on the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
   xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
   xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

   <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
     <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.query(".xspLinkViewColumn").attr
        ("target", "_blank");]]></xp:this.script>
   </xp:eventHandler>
   <xc:OneUILayout id="cc4cconeuilayout"
     navigationPath="/OneUI/SearchPage">
   <xp:this.facets>
      <xp:panel xp:key="LeftColumn" id="panel4">
         <xc:LeftOneUI id="cc4ccLeftOneUI"></xc:LeftOneUI>
      </xp:panel>
   </xp:this.facets>
   <xp:panel>
     <xp:label value="This is the result of the search page"
       id="label5" style="font-weight:bold">
     </xp:label>
     <xp:br></xp:br>
     <xp:br></xp:br>

     <xp:label value="Search String:" id="label1"></xp:label>
     <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#
       {param.search}"></xp:inputText>

     <xp:checkBox text="Cancelled Contracts Omitted" id="OmitCancelled" 
        value="#{viewScope.test}" style="padding-left:3.0em">
       <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="false">
         <xp:this.script><![CDATA[document.getElementById('#
           {id:button1}').click()]]></xp:this.script>
       </xp:eventHandler>
     </xp:checkBox>
     <xp:button value="Refresh Omitting"
        id="button1" style="margin-left:2.0em">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
           submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
           <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("hi")]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
     </xp:button>

    <xp:panel id="maincontentpanel">
       <xe:dynamicViewPanel rows="50" id="dynamicViewPanel1"
           width="100%" partialRefresh="true">
        <xe:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view">
           <xp:this.viewName>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:if(getComponent
                 ('OmitCancelled').isChecked()){
                      viewName = "ContractsFlatByYear"
                     }else {
                       viewName = "ContractsFlatByYearandCancelled"
                  }}]]>
           </xp:this.viewName>
          <xp:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:return param.search;}]]>
           </xp:this.search>
     </xp:dominoView>
    </xe:this.data>

   </xe:dynamicViewPanel>
  </xp:panel>
 </xp:panel>
</xc:OneUILayout>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example for automatically clicking a button on checkbox' onchange event:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:checkBox
        text="check it"
        id="checkBox1"
        value="#{viewScope.test}">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onchange"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                document.getElementById('#{id:button1}').click()
            ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:checkBox>
    <br />
    <xp:button
        value="Label"
        id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("hi")]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks knut.  I have updated my question with more information.  I attempted what you suggested but found it still only worked if I also clicked the button or somewhere else on the page

Comment: The only thing you have to change in your updated code is: .......................   `document.getElementById('#{id:button1}')` has to be in one line. You have a line break after `#` and because of that the pre-processor doesn't put the full client side id into that place.

Comment: Thank you. yes I have just done that and it now works. Is there a way I can hide the button but it still works?

Comment: Yes, just add `display:none` to button's style.

Comment: Thank you very much knut.  Just what I need.  I also found though that I had to change ('#id:button1}') to ("#id:button1}").  What exactly does the  value="#{viewScope.test}" do as it doesn't seem to be referenced further?  When I tried it I though you had to extract the viewScope value

Comment: `value="#{viewScope.test}"` binds the checkBox to view scope variable "test". The current value of checkBox is memorized as long the XPage "lives" in browser window. E.g. when you checked the box and do a content's partial refresh then the box stays checked.

Comment: `document.getElementById('#{id:button1}')` is as correct as .............. `document.getElementById("#{id:button1}")`